# Sometimes class members are not inherited by subclasses

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

When we create a template class `example1` which derives from another template class `example2`. The template class `example1` does not inherit systematically of `example2` members.

Consider the code bellow:

```
template<class T>
class example2 {
protected:
    int a;
public:
    int getA() const {return a;}
};

template<class T>
class example1 : public example2<T> {
    T* p;
public:
    void test() {
        example2<T>::a = 8;
    }
};
```

in the method `test` of the class `example1`, we have to use `example2<T>::` operator in order to be able to access to the member `a`. Otherwise, the complier generates an error: `'a' was not declared in this scope`.

I mean, why the complier does not recognize `a` in the class `example1`? Why we should specify `example2<T>::a` and not just `a`?

Thanks

Comment: You should force **dependent** type name. Alternatively, you may use `this->a`

Comment: You may look at [dependent_name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).